# htaccess query string redirect not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess

I have a situation where I want to actually see the url variable even though the rest of my htaccess site uses readable URLS.

The issue is that it is simply showing up as a page not found...

**This works...**

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.+)/from_all_files/$ pages/file.php?slug=$1&from=all-files
```

**This does not work**

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.+)?from=all-files$ pages/file.php?slug=$1&from=all-files
```

Im looking for the second one to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check the query string in a `RewriteRule`, which can only see the `REQUEST_URI`. You need to use the following instead:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^from=all-files$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/(.+)$ pages/file.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When you request http://example.com/files/some-file?from=all-files, the request will be internally rewritten to `pages/file.php?slug=some-file&from=all-files`. The Query String Append flag (`QSA`) will append the current query string to the one you're rewriting to.